# Converting CSV table data into YAML file using PHP arrays

Tags: php, arrays, csv, yaml, data-conversion

I have been assigned the following PHP task for Uni:

> 1) Export the Trades/Crafts table to Excel
>   2) Make three columns in Excel: Trade-ID, Category-ID, Trade-Name and organize it
>    3) Export the table as a .CSV file (easier for PHP manipulation)
>    4) Write a PHP script that creates a YAML file from CSV file that corresponds to the structure of  AppBundle / Resources / fixtures / prod / trades.yml
>
> How you do that exactly, is up to you. You are free to use whatever method you prefer, but the YAML file has to have
>   the right structure.

This is the trades.yml file (it was given as an example for  us to follow):

```
-
    ref: trade-1
    id: 1
    name: Plumber
    category: $trade-category-1
-
    ref: trade-16
    id: 16
    name: Electronic Engineer
    category: $trade-category-2
```

So as you might have guessed, I have a table with those 3 columns (Trade-ID, Category-ID and Trade-Name). The table contains about 150 rows with the name of many different kind of jobs, the type/branch of the job as category ID, and the ID of the job itself.

I exported that Excel table as a .csv file, as ordered. Now, I think I should use some function like `str_getcsv` or `fgetcsv`, which, how I understand it, reads the data in the CSV table and converts it into PHP arrays. After that, I need to convert those arrays into the YAML syntax format, but I read that's not particularly difficult.

Anyways, the number of 'titles/entries' in the YAML structure (ref, id, name, category) does not equal the number of columns in the CSV table (trade name, cat id, trade id), so I don't know how or where I should even start!

Also, for the "ref" part,I guess I would have to make it look like this: `trade-<ID of trade>` , but how can I do something like `"trade-" . $TradeID` inside an array? How can declare `$TradeID = <ID of the job>`? Can I refer to the CSV table's row and column I want, like `SELECT` in SQL? Or should I maybe use a WHILE loop which fetches all of the table's rows?

I have tried it like this:

```
<?php 

$file = fopen('MyTable.csv', 'r') or die('error');

$line = array();

while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  //$line is an array of the csv elements
  // print_r($line);
    foreach ($line as $key => $value) {
        # code...
    }
}
fclose($file);
```

But it outputs something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 1;1;Bituminiser; ) Array ( [0] => 1;2;Construction Dryer; ) Array ( [0] => 1;3;Concrete Driller and Cutter; ) Array ( [0] => 1;4;Concrete Block and Terrazzo Maker; ) Array ( [0] => 1;5;Well Builder; )
```

And so on... But I still have the other problem, plus the `[0]` inside each array.

I really can't figure it out. How can I convert the CSV table into a YAML file with the structure of `trades.yml` using PHP?

Comment: Try to ask one specific question at the time and give code related only to that problem. What is the question here? "What would you guys do?" ?

Comment: @MilanG what about now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
fgetcsv($file, 0, ';')
```

And look for more information in [PHP docs for `fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

However, I've made a sample script for you:

```php
<?php

$file = fopen('MyTable.csv', 'r') or die('error');

$yml = '';
$indent = str_repeat(' ', 4);
$keys = [
    'ref',
    'id',
    'name',
    'category',
];

while (($values = fgetcsv($file, 0, ';')) !== FALSE) {
    $yml .= "-\n";
    $arr = array_combine($keys, $values);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $yml .= "{$indent}{$key}: {$value}\n";
    }
}
fclose($file);

echo $yml;
```

Comment: What does the .= mean? Thanks for the anwer though!

Comment: I adjusted your anwer to what I needed. Thank you. I have a much clearer idea of how to handle this kind of tasks

Comment: `.=` means concatenation. It's the same as `$yml = $yml . "-\n"`. For more information look here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php (String operators)